# Determine Service Account for Airflow in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, google-kubernetes-engine, airflow-scheduler, kubernetes-operator

I am running Airflow in Kubernetes
One pod, 2 containers - webserver and scheduler.
KubernetesExecutor in configs

But due to organizational settings, the scheduler with the default service account can't work, not enough roles. I can't change this setting

```
{"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"pods is forbidden: User \"system:serviceaccount:<account_name>:default\" cannot list resource \"pods\" in API group \"\" in the namespace \"<namespace_name>\"","reason":"Forbidden","details":{"kind":"pods"},"code":403}
```

So I created Service Account with the needed `roles`, `roleBinging` and etc. How can I set Airflow to run the scheduler with that SA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the desired SA to use in your pod spec as discussed in the link below:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: my-pod
spec:
  serviceAccountName: build-robot
  automountServiceAccountToken: false
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. In my case `automountServiceAccountToken: true` was also required